# 2013 MIT Aquarium Hunt #1

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, explanation

The puzzle is *Alter Rival* from [2013 Aquarium Hunt](https://puzzles.mit.edu/aquarium/2013/1.pdf). Every article or post I found tells me it is a fairly easy puzzle.

[image]

The answer of the puzzle:

> DC Comics

What I tried: I noticed the capitalized letters at first, but connecting them seemed to make no sense. Then I looked back to the title. I tried to alter the capitalized names to their rivals and of course no effect. After I carefully read the introduction, I tried to find out where the customer is and I failed. I didn't go further because this is the first puzzle of a beginner-level puzzlehunt and shouldn't be too hard to solve.

Comment: You might be overthinking... a common thing to do in puzzle hunts. ROT13(Lbh jrer ba gur pbeerpg cngu.  V jbaqre jung lbh unq sbe gur evinyf.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Immediate things to notice in the surface reading...

> Title = Alter Rivals
>  Customer calls looking for Tannen but actually called McFly, these are rivals from Back to the Future
>  Notice the capitalized brands in the story

Collected data:

> VISA, BOEING, OMEGA, AT&T, DURACELL, MEGABLOKS
>  VBOADM (Not promising)

Solving data:

> Rivals
>  MASTERCARD, AIRBUS, ROLEX, VERIZON, ENERGIZER, LEGO
>  MARVEL (This is good!)

That's not the answer though:

> We need the rival of MARVEL
>  Notice the hint with "strip by strip" as in comic strip.

Answer:

> DCCOMICS

Thoughts on the title:

> I think the struggle the asker is having is focusing to hard on the word "alter".  In this case it is a bit of a red-herring, as there is nothing to "alter" in the puzzle.  As someone who understands comics, I see the play of "Alter Rivals" against "Alter Egos", a common theme in comics.

Comment: Thank you! I did get 'marvel' when I tried to solve it. But I don't think of altering its rival because I rarely read comics :(